# PHP MySQL Update Query Does Not Execute

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with my update query when users request a password reset.

It simply does nothing, It does show that the password has been reset according to the alert command, but the database does not reflect the update...

Any assistance would be great as I cannot see where I am going wrong...

```
if(isset($_GET["acc"]) && isset($_GET["np"])){
        $acc=decrypt(htmlspecialchars($_GET["acc"]));
        $np=decrypt(htmlspecialchars($_GET["np"]));
        //var_dump($acc);
        //var_dump($np);

        $query="UPDATE `master_profile` SET `password`=? where `email_address`=?";
            if ($stmt = $connection_link->prepare($query)){ 
                    // Bind the variables to the parameter as strings. 
                    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$np,$acc);
                    // Execute the statement.
                    if($stmt->execute()){
                        ?>
                        <script>
                        alert('Your password has been reset. Please login with your new password.');
                        </script>
                        <?
                        //echo "Updated {$stmt->affected_rows} rows";
                    }else{
                        echo '<h1>An Error Has Occoured. Please try again later.</h1>';
                    }
                    if ($stmt->errno) {
                      echo "FAILURE!!! " . $stmt->error;
                    }
                // Close the prepared statement.
                    $stmt->close();
                }
    }
```

**Update**

Changed `if($stmt->execute(array($np,$acc))){}` as suggested below but it simply gives me an error `An Error Has Occoured. Please try again later.`, How can i catch this error and report the proper error?

I have tried `$stmt->error;` and `$connection_link->error;` but both just give an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using anonymous placeholders I think you need to omit your  bind statement. Instead you would place the parameters in the execute as an array and in order of appearance in the statement

```
if($stmt->execute(array($acc, $np)){}
```

You would omit this line

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$np,$acc);
```

Comment: When I update it like you suggested, I get the error from the else statement `An Error Has Occoured. Please try again later.`

Comment: Try removing the back ticks

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, currently the execute code looks like this `if($stmt->execute(array($np,$acc))){}` what back ticks are you referring to?

Comment: The ones in your $query variable.